# Python3.7 + AWS

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, amazon-web-services

Необходимо загрузить программу на виртуалку AWS. Но при загрузке выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "music.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "music.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Как я понял он ругается, что не установлен селениум, но он у меня уже установлен

```
Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.25.3
```

Тогда в чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: `но у меня он уже установлен` – а должен быть установлен не у вас, а в облаке.

Comment: Каким образом я могу загрузить selenium на облако?

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто установить нужный модуль в директорию проекта выполнив команду `pip install <library_name> -t ./` в корневой папке. Или ещё лучше не в корневой, а в специальной, чтобы не засорять проект. Пример:

Файл `somelib.py` в папке `libs`:

```py
CONST = 3.141519265358979
```

Файл `main.py` в корневой директории:

```py
# Добавление папки libs в интерпретатор Питона
import sys
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(os.path.join(cwd, 'libs'))

# Теперь можно легко использовать любые модули из libs
from somelib import CONST
print(CONST)
```

А устанавливать новые тогда можно командой `pip install -t lib/ <library_name>`. Вообще, информация о подготовке проекта есть на сайте AWS: [How do I build an AWS Lambda deployment package for Python?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/)